# Quality of PLS Regression at different interaction levels

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, model, partial-least-squares

I am fairly new to multivariate statistics and have run into the following situation:

I have a data set of 12 response sets based on a Likert scale (1-5), data which is commonly (in social research) treated as more-or-less interval scale / quantitative. Only about half of the responses show a normal distribution, many show a right-skewed distribution.

The aim is to identify correlations within this response data set. Using XLSTAT for Excel, I started out with multiple regression and identified two main influential IVs (R2 over all variables = 0,32) for a particular DV (selected from among the 12 variables). I then re-ran the calculations for 2 and 3 interaction levels. While the R2 of the results understandably increased considerably (to 0,85 and 0,94), the variables that now were most influential (according to standardized coefficient value for significant results) changed with each interaction level. While for no interactions, multicollinearity was low (tolerance 0.6-0.8, VIF always under 2), with 2 or 3 interaction levels multicollinearity soared (2 levels: VIFs over 400, 3 levels: VIFs in the millions).

Assuming that multicollinearity and probably suppressor variables were the problem, I then changed to PLS regression, again 11 IVs for one DV. With no interactions accounted for, I got a Q2 cumulated of 0.12, R2Y cum=0.26 and R2X cum=0.25. The most influential IV according to VIP value was the same as at the non-interactions multiple regression (with VIP value of 1.4). The same with 2 interaction levels again showed that same IV (VIP now 2.0) at the top (and the previously second-most significant IV still at second place), but Q2cum slightly down at 0.09, R2Y cum improved at 0.41, R2X cum lower at 0.09. Trying now for 3 interaction levels, the rank of most influential IVs shifted completely, with a combination of three IVs showing a VIP of 2.4, the previously most important IV still being in third place (VIP of 2.1). However, model quality is now terrible, with a Q2cum of -0.03 (R2Y/X cum about the same as for 2 interaction levels).

What I would like to understand from this:

1. I assume that higher VIP values for increased interaction levels come from more complex modeling due to more interactions being accounted for, but the Q2cum for 3 interaction levels shows that model predictive quality has dropped. Why would this be the case? Which of the three PLS models (0/2/3 interaction levels) will serve me best, or does the low Q2 mean that none of them is significant at all? Assuming that Q2 and R2 were the same for all three, would the higher interaction model have the greatest explanatory power?
2. How should I interpret the model quality values (Q2/R2x/y cum)? In particular, is Q2cum (predictive power of model) the primary quality factor to consider, or are reasonably R2x/y cum levels (actual explanative power of model) sufficient? 
   Since R2y reflects the variation of the DV explained by the IVs (if I understood correctly), then I assume that the R2y value is more significant for the quality of my model than R2x, correct?
3. How bad is it that my IVs do not all show a good normal distribution for all this? How robust is PLS regression in this case?

Thanks for your patience with a newbie, I appreciate simple and understandable explanations, thanks a lot!!

Comment: You may want to check out the recent publication on this subject http://www.researchgate.net/publication/264936800_Interpretation_of_Variable_Importance_in_Partial_Least_Squares_with_Significance_multivariate_correlation_(SMC) Success !
Thanh Tran﻿